# Jquery - clicking on links doesn't change the div content

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to Jquery. I am trying with a small example. Clicking on the link doesn't change the div content. I have tried the below code but it shows all the div content and it doesn't change when I click on each link. For example, clicking on 'about' should display 'divAbout' and hide others and so on.

I have tried all the solution on the internet and nothing didn't work for me. Please, let me know what mistake I have done. It would be of great help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
     <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#home").click(function(){
         $("#divHome").show();

       });

      $("#about").click(function(){
         $("divs").hide();
          $("#divAbout").show();
       });

       $("#help").click(function(){
          $("divs").hide();
           $("#divHelp").show();
       });

      });

    </script>
  </head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <body>
      <div class="Maincontainer">
          <div class= "header">
            <h2 class="text-color">Info</h2>
                 <ul class="links">

                   <li id="home"><a href="#home" class="link">Home</a></li>
                   <li id="about"><a href="#about" class="link" >About</a</li>
                   <li id="help"><a href="#help" class="link" >Help</a></li>
                   <li id="profile"><a href="#profile" class="link" >Profile</a>

                   </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
              <div class="divs" >
                   <div class="divs" id="divHome">Display the home content</div>
                   <div class="divs" id="divAbout">about</div>
                   <div class="divs" id="divHelp">Help</div>
                   <div class="divs" id="divProfile">Profile</div>
              </div>

             <div class="footer">
               <h4>Copyright 2017. All CONTENT, IMAGES AND TEXT COPYRIGHTED</h4>
             </div>

           </div>
        </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: `$("divs")` is wrong. It should be `$("div")` or `$(".divs")`

Comment: Correct should be $("div")

Comment: I tried with $(".divs") but by default, it shows all the divs and when I click About, it clears. But what I want is by default it should show home div and when I click about and other it should its respective div. Please, help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the class divs from the parent div. Only the items div should have this class.

```
      <div class="Maincontainer">
          <div class= "header">
            <h2 class="text-color">Info</h2>
                 <ul class="links">

                   <li id="home"><a href="#home" class="link">Home</a></li>
                   <li id="about"><a href="#about" class="link" >About</a</li>
                   <li id="help"><a href="#help" class="link" >Help</a></li>
                   <li id="profile"><a href="#profile" class="link" >Profile</a>

                   </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
              <div>
                   <div class="divs" id="divHome">Display the home content</div>
                   <div class="divs" id="divAbout">about</div>
                   <div class="divs" id="divHelp">Help</div>
                   <div class="divs" id="divProfile">Profile</div>
              </div>

             <div class="footer">
               <h4>Copyright 2017. All CONTENT, IMAGES AND TEXT COPYRIGHTED</h4>
             </div>

           </div>
        </body>
```

and your JQuery should access it with

```
 $(".divs").hide();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working but I have one problem. In the beginning, it shows all the divs and  when I click on home then it shows the home div content. But I need home content should be shown by default not all the divs.

Comment: add a style  .divs{display:none;} to hide all by default. Then in the div that you do want to show by default add a style="display:block"